# Referential Integrity Constraint Violation when saving Many to Many - Ebean, Play, Yaml, Tests

Tags: java, testing, yaml, ebean, playframework-2.2

I have a Play 2.2.1 Java application using Ebean, for which I have a testing environment that creates a database with initial data from a .yml file:

```
criteria:
  - !!models.Criterion
    name: "testcriterion1"
    id: 10
  - !!models.Criterion
    name: "testcriterion2"
    id: 20

scoringmodels:
  - !!models.ScoringModel
    id: 10
    criteria:
        - !!models.Criterion
            id: 10
```

The Models look like this:

```
@Entity
public class ScoringModel extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    @ManyToMany
    public List<Criterion> criteria;
}

@Entity
public class Criterion extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    @Required
    public String name;
}
```

Before each test the database is cleared and rebuild:

```
@Before
public void createCleanDb() {
    Ebean.execute(Ebean.createCallableSql(dropDdl));
    Ebean.execute(Ebean.createCallableSql(createDdl));
    //Create initial data
    Map<String,List<Object>> all = (Map<String,List<Object>>)Yaml.load("initial-data.yml");
    Ebean.save(all.get("scoringmodels"));
    Ebean.save(all.get("criteria"));
}
```

I get the following error when running my tests:

> Referential integrity constraint violation:
>   "FK_SCORING_MODEL_CRITERION_CR_02: PUBLIC.SCORING_MODEL_CRITERION
>   FOREIGN KEY(CRITERION_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.CRITERION(ID) (10)"; SQL
>   statement: [error] insert into scoring_model_criterion
>   (scoring_model_id, criterion_id) values (?, ?) [23506-172] [error]
>   at
>   com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.ExeUpdateSql.execute(ExeUpdateSql.java:76)
>   [error]     at
>   com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersistExecute.executeSqlUpdate(DefaultPersistExecute.java:115)
>   [error]     at
>   com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestUpdateSql.executeNow(PersistRequestUpdateSql.java:44)
>   [error]     at
>   com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequest.executeStatement(PersistRequest.java:74)
>   [error]     at
>   com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestUpdateSql.executeOrQueue(PersistRequestUpdateSql.java:49)
>   [error]     at
>   com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.executeSqlUpdate(DefaultPersister.java:139)
>   [error]     at
>   com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.saveAssocManyIntersection(DefaultPersister.java:999)
>   [error]     at
>   com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.saveMany(DefaultPersister.java:730)
>   [error]     at
>   com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.saveAssocMany(DefaultPersister.java:631)
>   [error]     at
>   com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.insert(DefaultPersister.java:339)
>   [error]     at
>   com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.saveEnhanced(DefaultPersister.java:310)
>   [error]     at
>   com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.saveRecurse(DefaultPersister.java:280)
>   [error]     at
>   com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.save(DefaultPersister.java:248)
>   [error]     at
>   com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.save(DefaultServer.java:1759)
>   [error]     at
>   com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.save(DefaultServer.java:1737)
>   [error]     at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.save(Ebean.java:526) [error]
>   at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.save(Ebean.java:533) [error]     at
>   controllers.BaseControllerTest.createCleanDb(BaseControllerTest.java:53)
>   [error]     ... [error] Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException:
>   Referentielle Integrität verletzt: "FK_SCORING_MODEL_CRITERION_CR_02:
>   PUBLIC.SCORING_MODEL_CRITERION FOREIGN KEY(CRITERION_ID) REFERENCES
>   PUBLIC.CRITERION(ID) (10)"

Any hint or answer would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I resolved the issue by changing the order in which the objects were persisted. As scoring model references criteria, these need to be inserted first.
Accordingly it must be:

```
@Before
public void createCleanDb() {
    Ebean.execute(Ebean.createCallableSql(dropDdl));
    Ebean.execute(Ebean.createCallableSql(createDdl));
    //Create initial data
    Map<String,List<Object>> all = (Map<String,List<Object>>)Yaml.load("initial-data.yml");
    Ebean.save(all.get("criteria"));
    Ebean.save(all.get("scoringmodels"));
}
```